# If $ H , K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $HK$ is subgroup of $G$ then $|H|$, $|K|$ aren't co-prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The statement I'm trying to understand is as written in the title :

> If $ H , K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $HK$ is subgroup of $G$ then
>   $|H|$, $|K|$ aren't co-prime?

I tried to find a counter example in $S_3$ and in cyclic groups and I couldn't find anything.

I know that $|H|$ and $|K|$ must divide $|HK|$ (by Lagrange theorem) but I think that it's not correct that $|H|$ and $|K|$ must have common divisor larger than 1 (that is, not co-prime) because it is possible (I guess) that $|HK| = 36$ and $|H| = 9 $, $|K| =4$ but $|H|$ and $|K|$ are co-prime.

The only problem is that I came up with this example by guessing it's possible whereas it is possible that such a $HK$ subgroup doesn't exists not matter what $G$ is.

I'm confused - If the statement is correct please give me an hint how to prove it and if it's not correct please suggest a counter-example.

Comment: The answer is no, and $S_3$ with $|H|=3$ and $|K|=2$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* $G = \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_8, H = \mathbb Z_4 \times (0), K = (0) \times \mathbb Z_8.$

$|H|$ and $|K|$ need not have to coprime to satisfy the condition $|H \cap K|=1.$

*Added:* "If $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $HK$ is subgroup of $G$ then $|H|, |K|$ aren't co-prime." This statement is not correct. Take $G = \mathbb Z_{36}.$ Consider the subroup $H:= \left< \bar 4 \right>, K:= \left< \bar 9 \right>.$ Since $G$ is cyclic, $HK$ is a subgroup of $G.$ But $|H|, |K|$ are co-prime.

Comment: I don't completely understand what's the group $G$. I will try to understand what you mean. That is why I was looking for a counter example in $S_n$ or a simple $Z_i$ group.

Comment: $G$ is the direct sum of $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_8$. It's an abelian group (and non-cyclic). So $HK$ is a subgroup of $G.$ Now $|H|, |K|$ is not co-prime. But still we have $|H \cap K|=1.$ For direct sum see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum

Comment: Thanks for the link! Excuse me again but I don't understand what is the point you are trying to show. I'm trying to understand if it is possible that $|H|$ and $|K|$ are co-prime in this case.

Comment: I thought you were saying to have $|H \cap K|=1,$ one must have $|H|, |K|$ are coprime. The first example shows that this is not the case always. Now see the added part for answer of the question in the heading (I missed that question in the first reading). If you have any more question, feel free to ask.

Comment: But how do you know how much elements exist in $H:= \left< \bar 4 \right>$ and $K:= \left< \bar 9 \right>$? BTW, I fixed my question to contain the title so no one will be confused in the future.

Comment: *Hint:* Both the groups $H$ and $K$ are cyclic subgrops of $G.$ So $|H|, |K|$ are the order of the element $\bar 4, \bar 9$ respectively. (Actually in this case you can do more. Write down all the elements of $\mathbb Z_{36}$ and see which element is in $H$ and in $K.$)

Comment: Oh so we get $|H|:= |\left< \bar 4 \right>| = 9$ because $4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4 = 0$ and we get $|K|:= |\left< \bar 9 \right>|= 4  $ because $9+9+9+9 = 0$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes! For $\bar 4, 9$ is the least +ve integer satisfying $9 \cdot \bar 4 = \bar 0.$ So the order is $9.$ Similarly for $\bar 9.$

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot see the relevance of your example to the question that was asked. The question says nothing at all about $H \cap K$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: The question was edited later. At first the question was only in the title, not in the body. I misunderstood the question also (See my second comment). The *Added* part actually addressed the question. Not the first example.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $HK$ is a subgroup, then $|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$

Comment: Let me see if I understand correct. We know that $|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$ and we also know that $\frac{|H|}{|H\cap K|}$ and $\frac{|K|}{|H\cap K|}$ and therefore we can imply that $|H|,|K|$ aren't co-prime?

Comment: If $|H \cap K| \neq 1$ then they are not (of course) co-prime, as $H \cap K < H$ and $H\cap K < K$. On the other hand, it's easy to make an example of $H$ and $K$ s.t. $|H|$ and $|K|$ are coprime, thus no relation is implied about coprimality of $H$ and $K$.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jonas! I'm trying to understand what you wrote using few examples.